# Why is IE 11 not rendering :after element, showing css as crossed out in dev tools?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have an angular app with two font icons in a given screen. These are rendered just fine in chrome, firefox and edge, but on IE 11 they do not display. The icons are to be rendered as the `content` of the `:after` pseudo class, which according to my research should work fine on IE 9 and up. However, on IE, these are simply not rendered.

As you can see in the screenshot, the :after element is not in the DOM displayed in the dev tools, and the css is correct but shows crossed out in dev tools:

[image: IE 11 shows css for :after element crossed out, nothing is rendered]

The relevant CSS that is compiled and actually used in the screen showing the issue is like so:

```
.profile-picture[_ngcontent-vem-9]:after {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    content: "\E3B0";
    font-size: 48px;
    top: 32px;
    left: 25px
}
.profile-picture[_ngcontent-vem-9] .title[_ngcontent-vem-9],
.profile-picture[_ngcontent-vem-9]:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    transition-duration: .3s
}
```

The rules above the crossed out ones are unrelated. But since someone asked to see them, here they are:

[image]

The question is: **why is this happening, and how to fix it?**

Comment: Well, what's above those rules in your inspector? it's cut off on the screenshot

Comment: Have you tried `font-family: "Material Icons"`? It's very strange name for font. Also I have seen that even if `:after` element is shown correctly IE still crosses out it's rules as it was overwritten by some other rule (usually it shows element itself rules as applied ones).

Comment: @Justinas Even if it is a strange name for a font, omitting the quotes is not an error, and if the font can't be used, nothing bad will happen. So that's not the problem; something else is going on in the OP's situation.

Comment: @MrLister Well, since icons are shipped as font, than `font can't be used` *will* make icons to disappear.

Comment: Have you tried using Material Icons as described in this resource: https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/ ?

Comment: @Huangism the rules above are unrelated, nothing is overriding the crossed out rules there...

Comment: @Justinas Yeah that was my thought, the quotes were removed by a css compressor.. but adding them back did not make a difference. Also the rules above are unrelated, nothing is overriding the crossed out rules. It's a mystery! I did try using as they suggest, same results... I have stepped away from it because I don't want all those class declarations, but anyways they didn't help, same thing.

Comment: @EdyBourne Can you provide SO Snippet with your issue so that we can play around? Maybe it's as simple as wrong `content` code?

Comment: The problem probably lies in the font not being rendered, not the element, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879892/1744461)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IE crossing out pseudo element CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875232/ie-crossing-out-pseudo-element-css)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, the after element on an `<a>` tag wasn't rendered in IE11, though I could see the CSS style for it. Freddie's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964115/5325840) solved the issue for me. Add this to the css `display: block;`