# Star rating using Font Awesome doesn't work properly on Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

The star rating using Font Awesome defined by width provided below is working fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on Edge and IE doesn't. Anyone know what could it be?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcfm4npn/5/)

Chrome and Firefox

[image: Chrome and Firefox]

Edge and IE

[image: Edge and IE]

```css
.star-rating {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
}
.star-rating:before,
.star-rating:after {
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";
  display: block;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.star-rating:after {
  color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-rating.s0:after {
  width: 0%;
}
.star-rating.s1:after {
  width: 10%;
}
.star-rating.s2:after {
  width: 20%;
}
.star-rating.s3:after {
  width: 30%;
}
.star-rating.s4:after {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating.s5:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.star-rating.s6:after {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating.s7:after {
  width: 70%;
}
.star-rating.s8:after {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating.s9:after {
  width: 90%;
}
.star-rating.s10:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="star-rating s7"></span>
```

Comment: *"Anyone know what could it be?"* - Yes, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961123/2813224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug that the M$ browser has when dealing with pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879892/2813224). The workaround is:

> ```
>  .star-rating {overflow: hidden;}
> ```

Under a browser that is designed to comply to standards (i.e. real browsers such as Chrome and Firefox), just having `.star-rating::after` is good enough. Unfortunately, M$ browsers are garbage.

Check the styles in the developer tools and you'll see that all of the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` are crossed out. This is one of the many bugs IE is infested with. Here are the symptoms:

- The developer tools have all of the pseudo element styles crossed out
- Although the styles look like they are disabled according to the developer tool, the majority of them are not.
- If there is a behavior that is unique to only IE and/or Edge, then the bug's secondary side effect has manifested. There are style properties that are ignored when applied to a pseudo element when the parent element doesn't implicitly have the property itself.

> **Issue:** In OP's specific case, the pseudo element: `.star-rating::after` property: `overflow: hidden` was ignored because IE requires the parent: `.star-rating` to have it as well.
>
> ---
>
> **Workaround:** Apply `overflow: hidden` to `.star-rating`

### Demo (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE)

```css
.star-rating {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.star-rating:before,
.star-rating:after {
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";
  display: block;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.star-rating:after {
  color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-rating.s0:after {
  width: 0%;
}
.star-rating.s1:after {
  width: 10%;
}
.star-rating.s2:after {
  width: 20%;
}
.star-rating.s3:after {
  width: 30%;
}
.star-rating.s4:after {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating.s5:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.star-rating.s6:after {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating.s7:after {
  width: 70%;
}
.star-rating.s8:after {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating.s9:after {
  width: 90%;
}
.star-rating.s10:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="star-rating s7"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to the `.star-rating::before, .star-rating::after` rule.

```css
.star-rating {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
}
.star-rating:before,
.star-rating:after {
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";
  display: block;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.star-rating:after {
  color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-rating.s0:after {
  width: 0%;
}
.star-rating.s1:after {
  width: 10%;
}
.star-rating.s2:after {
  width: 20%;
}
.star-rating.s3:after {
  width: 30%;
}
.star-rating.s4:after {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating.s5:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.star-rating.s6:after {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating.s7:after {
  width: 70%;
}
.star-rating.s8:after {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating.s9:after {
  width: 90%;
}
.star-rating.s10:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="star-rating s7"></span>
```